# Proof that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j$ converges if $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \|C_j\|$ converges

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, divergent-series

> $C_j$ is a sequence of **matrices** in $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ and the identity 
>   $$\max_{j,k}|A_{j,k}|\leq \|A\|\leq n\max_{j,k}|A_{j,k}|$$
>   is known. Show that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j$ converges if $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \|C_j\|$ does.

I tried a proof by contradiction:

If $\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j$ **does not** converge, then for any $0\leq m <\infty$ there exists an $n>m$ such that

$$\max\Big|\sum_{j=0}^m C_j\Big|\leq\max\Big|\sum_{j=m}^n C_j\Big|$$

Now since any matrix norm satisfies $\|A+B\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|$ we can say that

$$\Big\|\sum_{j=m}^n C_j\Big\| \leq \sum_{j=m}^n \| C_j \|$$

Because of the above identity we can write

$$\max\Big|\sum_{j=0}^m C_j\Big|\leq\max\Big|\sum_{j=m}^n C_j\Big|\leq\Big\|\sum_{j=m}^n C_j\Big\| \leq \sum_{j=m}^n \| C_j \|$$

but we can pick $m$ arbitrarily large, hence $\sum_{j=m}^n \| C_j \|$ diverges when $m\to \infty$.

So I hopefully showed that the $\|C_j\|$ series diverges if the $C_j$ series does, too, which is the "other direction" of the implication to be shown. As pointed out in the comments, this forgets the case where the series oscillates, but would the proof work out if that were taken care of?

Edit: I forgot to mention the $C_j$ are matrices, I hope that doesn't change much.

Comment: I would prove instead that every Cauchy sequence of complex numbers/vectors  converges. and an absolutely convergent series becomes clearly a Cauchy sequence with $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k$, since $|a_n-a_m| \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n |c_k| \to 0$  as $n >m > N \to \infty$.

Comment: @user1952009 Can you tell whether there is a mistake in my attempt?

Comment: the main problem is that it seems you are assuming the negation of "$|\sum_n u_n|$ diverges to $+\infty$" is "$|\sum_n u_n|$ converges", but a series can diverge by oscillating. and the first line means that if $M_n$ converges in matrix norm,  then $M_n$ converges for each of its coefficient (the converse is also of course true, because of the definition of a norm)

Comment: @user1952009 I see, dang... Maybe I can exclude that case by proving that if it oscillates, the series of the norms is infinite.

Comment: yes, but it is much simpler to consider the direct $\implies$

Comment: @user1952009 Of course, thank you

Comment: @user1952009 One more thing, I forgot to mention this is about matrices, does that change a lot?

Comment: I know, but the first line tells you that the convergence in norm of a sequence of matrices implies the convergence in Frobenius norm, i.e. seing it as a sequence of $n^2$ vectors   (this is true only in finite dimensional vector spaces)